# jQuery moving DOM element outside parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a layout like:

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="logo">Logo Here</div>
    <nav class="menu">Menu Here</nav>
</header>

<div class="container">
    <aside class="aside">
        <!-- Here are the Buttons that Filters the Content in .main-content class -->
    </aside>
    <div class="main-content">
        <!-- The list of contents here are shown according to the filter in sidebar -->
        <!-- The contents are lets say only tables and Ajax button does its filter -->
        <div class="export-link">Export Link</div> <!-- This export list is created by Ajax and for every filter value the link changes -->
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="some-links">Some Links</div>
</footer>
```

I want that `div.export-link` to place in `nav.menu`.

At first I did something like

```
if($('.new__nav-class').length === 0 ){
    $('.menu, .export-link').wrapAll('<div class="new__nav-class"> </div>');
}
```

This places the `div.export-link` and `nav.menu` inside new `div.new__nav-class` in the header section, and I can apply CSS to make it pretty.

However the problem is it doesn't take the filter value anymore. The `link` inside the `.export-link` used to change according to the filter like `href="/page?Thisfilter-Thatfilter"`, but since I put the wrapper in top of the div and placed it in the menu, the link has become static.

Any solution how to fix this?

Comment: You leave out one critical piece of info, which is, how does the export-link div get updated? If it's an ajax response that fills the export-link div with the new link, you need to look at the ajax success handler and change that to modify the export-link in its new location. One option to fix this without changing too much could be to clone the export-link class instead of moving it.

Comment: I am not sure if the `export-link` div gets updated. I can only see the `a href` link being changed after I filter. I do hover over it. Normally the `export-link a` contains `href="/page?export"` and after applying the filter the same link changes to `href="/page?exportApplyingThisFilterThatFilter"` etc. But everytime I sort the link changes.

Comment: Open Chrome Inspector > Network and look to see if ajax requests are being made to keep that link up to date. If you can't figure out how or where to change the javascript, then you're pretty much limited to using the div that you already have. Try using position: absolute to put the field where you want it on the page.

Comment: yes, whenever the filter is updated I see new ajax request in Chrome's Inspector network. Thanks for the suggestions about absolute, I wonder if that'd display differently in different browsers/devices. But I'll give a try

Answer (score 0):

Check your DocType

Try using `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Or `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Comment: You shouldn't use those doctypes with HTML5 elements like <footer> or <header>

Comment: I have the doc types, just omitted from here... BTW does it concern my question what the doctype is ?

Answer (score 0):

Position: absolute would probably work fine for you if you just need to move the field somewhere else on the page. Just make its parent position: relative and it should look fine for all browsers. (Of course, you'll want to check.)

Comment: That's what my question was. I tried with absolute position but it screws all my design, as its parent's position is not the same. As my question says, I was jumping the parent element from one `div` to `header`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the ajaxStop event to see if the link has changed and copy it into the new div you want to have. ajaxStop is an event that occurs whenever an ajax response is returned to the page. The javascript below says to wait for an ajax response. When a response occurs, get the html inside the #old-div and put it in the #new-div:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="new-div"></div>
  </header>
  <div class="other-container">  
    <div id="old-div">link stays updated here</div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        var link = $('#old-div').html();
        $('#new-div').html( link );
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```